# Get the hostname/DNSName of a Hyper-V VM (while VM is OFF) using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Can anyone figure out a clever way to grab the Hostname of a VM while it's still Off using PowerShell?
I only know how to grab the VM's Hostname while the VM is still On.

PS:  I want the hostname/DNSName of the VM (not to be confused with the VM Name); which aren't the same thing.

Comment: if it has never been run, then i doubt that the info is stored anywhere. if it _has_ been run once, then your DHCP server, your AD database, and perhaps your firewall logs seem likely to have the info.

Comment: These are VMs that have run before.  Could you please post a programmatic PS solution querying DHCP and/or AD?

Comment: according to this page >>> Active Directory: Get-ADComputer Default and Extended Properties - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki — https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12056.active-directory-get-adcomputer-default-and-extended-properties.aspx <<< the default returned properties from `Get-ADComputer` include `.DNSHostName`. so you otta be able to get it from there IF your AD stores the VMName as the AD computer name.

Comment: Unfortunately, AD stores the actual hostnames, not HyperV VM names; at least, not on our AD database.  I was hoping for a way to grab that information from the Virtual Host itself, if at all possible.

Comment: ah! i had hoped your ADComputerName items would be the VM name. [*sigh ...*] i have no idea how or what the VMHost stores. your firewall and DHCP stuff will all be the hostname with no way to cross reference that to your VN name. i'm stuck ... you likely otta find a hyper-v specific site to ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
get-vm |select-object -ExpandProperty network* |select-object -ExpandProperty ipaddresses |Resolve-DnsName
```

to grab the VM's IP address and do a reverse DNS lookup on it.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the show here, but I took Greyula-Reyula's quite efficient answer and turned it into a function that gives more feedback on why you may be getting no output from it. I'm relatively new to this level of scripting, so I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but I'm a fan of "verbosity" and try to make my scripts as easy-to-follow for myself as possible in case I want to mess with them again later. :)

```powershell
Function Get-HVComputerName
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Alias("ServerName")][Parameter()]
        $HVHostName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [Alias("ComputerName")][Parameter()]
        [string[]]$VMName
    )

    #VMWare.VimAutomation.Core also has a "Get-VM" cmdlet, 
    #so unload that module if it's present first
    If (Get-Module -Name VMware*) { Remove-Module -Name VMware* -Verbose:$false }

    If (!(Get-Module -Name Hyper-V)) { Import-Module -Name Hyper-V -Verbose:$false }

    $VMs = Get-VM -ComputerName $HVHostName -Name "*$VMName*"
    If ($VMs)
    {
        $DNSNameArr = @()
        If ($VMs.Count -gt 1)
        {
            Write-Host "`nFound the following VMs on Hyper-V server $HVHostName with name like `"`*$VMName`*`":" -ForegroundColor Green
            $VMs.Name | Out-Default
            Write-Host ""
        }

        ForEach ($VM in $VMs)
        {
            $Name = $VM.Name
            If ($VerbosePreference -eq "Continue")
            {
                Write-Host ""
            }
            Write-Verbose "VM: $Name found on server $HVHostName"
            If ($VM.State -ne "Running")
            {
                Write-Verbose "VM: $Name is not in a 'running' state. No IP address will be present.`n"
                Continue
            }
            $VMNetAdapters = $VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters
            If ($VMNetAdapters)
            {
                Write-Verbose "VM $Name - Found the following network adapter(s)"
                If ($VerbosePreference -eq "Continue")
                {
                    $VMNetAdapters | Out-Default
                }
                ForEach ($NetAdapter in $VMNetAdapters)
                {
                    $AdapterName = $NetAdapter.Name
                    $IPAddresses = $NetAdapter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddresses
                    If ($IPAddresses)
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "VM: $Name - Adapter: `"$AdapterName`" - Found the following IP address(es) on network adapter"
                        If ($VerbosePreference -eq "Continue")
                        {
                            $IPAddresses | Out-Default
                        }

                        ForEach ($IP in $IPAddresses)
                        {
                            $DNSName = $IP | Resolve-DnsName -Verbose:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                            If ($DNSName)
                            {
                                $DNSFound = $true
                                $VMDNS = [PSCustomObject]@{
                                    VMName = $Name
                                    IP = $IP
                                    DNSName = $DNSName.NameHost
                                }
                                $DNSNameArr += $VMDNS
                            }
                            Else
                            {
                                Write-Warning "VM: $Name - Adapter: `"$AdapterName`" - IP: $IP - No DNS name found"
                                Continue
                            }
                        }
                        If (!($DNSFound))
                        {
                            Write-Warning "VM: $Name - No DNS entries found for any associated IP addresses"
                        }
                        Else
                        {
                            $DNSFound = $false
                        }
                    }
                    Else
                    {
                        Write-Warning "VM: $Name - Adapter: `"$AdapterName`" - No IP address assigned to adapter"
                        Continue
                    }
                }
            }
            Else
            {
                Write-Warning "VM: $Name - No Network adapters found"
                Continue
            }
        }
        If ($DNSNameArr)
        {
            If ($VerbosePreference -eq "Continue")
            {
                Write-Host ""
            }
            Return $DNSNameArr
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Warning "No DNS names found for VM(s) with name like $VMName on server $HVHostName"   
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Warning "No VM found on server $HVHostName with name like $VMName"        
    }
} #End function Get-HVComputerName
```